# Magento: Custom attribute ranges in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

**1) In Magento I have the possibility to set the price in ranges like this:**

[Price ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X330B.png)

**2) Beside that I can easily manipulate the range and give it some individual values like:**

[Individual price ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzvz2.png)

> What I need is a custom attribute e.g. height but with the same functionalities like the price attribute (Range and individual values).

I already tried this solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60467/how-to-group-numeric-attribute-ranges-similar-to-prices-in-layered-navigation
It would give me the range which I need but unfortunately not the individual part which I mentioned in part 2).

**Could anyone give me some advice how to achieve it?**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [Improved Layered Navigation](https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html) extension.

To create a new numeric attribute (e.g. length, width, height) please follow these steps:

1. Go to admin panel > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Create New
2. Choose catalog input type ‘Price’ for numeric attributes if you would like to use sliders for them.
3. Set the ‘Use in Layered Navigation’ option to ‘Filterable’.
4. Once you create the ‘price’ attributes please go to Catalog > Improved Navigation > Filters and click ‘Load’ button. After that the numeric attributes will appear in the list of filters.